# How to add video calling functionality in Ionic-react app, using capacitor, with Zoom SDK(or any other)

Tags: zoom-sdk, ionic-react, videosdk.live

I want to add a video calling feature in my ionic-react app with capacitor, I see that there is a zoom SDK plugin but there is no documentation avaliablle for react, can some give me a react code that I can implement in that

As ZOOM SDK docs was not available I tried [*https://docs.videosdk.live/react/guide/video-and-audio-calling-api-sdk/quick-start*](https://stackoverflow.com) but its not working in ionic app

Comment: What's the plugin you're trying to use?  You can use any Capacitor or most cordova plugins with Ionic React.  If there is no Capacitor/Cordova plugin, you will need to write a Capacitor plugin first before you can use it in Ionic React.